# How to list all names loaded in in an ipython sessions?

Tags: python, ipython

I am injecting variables and functions into my default ipython namespace by dropping some `*.py` files into `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`.

I can list names that are newly created in an ipython session by typing `%who` or `%who_ls`. However the names defined in my startup files do not show up. Is there a magic function or a way to list all names introduced in the startup directory into an active ipython interactive session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern searching via [`%psearch`](http://%25psearch%20[options]%20PATTERN%20[OBJECT%20TYPE]%20%20Note:%20?%20can%20be%20used%20as%20a%20synonym%20for%20%25psearch,%20at%20the%20beginning%20or%20at%20the%20end:%20both%20a*?%20and%20?a*%20are%20equivalent%20to%20'%25psearch%20a*'.%20%20Still,%20the%20rest%20of%20the%20command%20line%20must%20be%20unchanged%20(options%20come%20first),%20so%20for%20example%20the%20following%20forms%20are%20equivalent%20%20%25psearch%20-i%20a*%20function%20-i%20a*%20function?%20?-i%20a*%20function).  To list all objects NOT in the builtin space, use:

```
%psearch -e builtin *
```

> %psearch [options] PATTERN [OBJECT TYPE]
>
> Note: ? can be used as a synonym for %psearch, at the beginning or at
>   the end: both a*? and ?a* are equivalent to '%psearch a*'.  Still, the
>   rest of the command line must be unchanged (options come first), so
>   for example the following forms are equivalent
>
> %psearch -i a* function
>   -i a* function?
>   ?-i a* function